# No module named 'cx_Oracle' - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Galera, boa tarde.

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão com o banco de dados oracle, porém quando eu executo o meu script dá esse erro de No module named 'cx_Oracle'.
Porém eu tenho isso instalado na máquina e estou usando o python 3.6. Alguém sabe solucionar isso?

```
import cx_Oracle
uid = "user"    # usuário
pwd = "pwd"   # senha
db = "(DESCRIPTION =    (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = UBR001001-125)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=corps0)))  "  #string de conexão do Oracle, configurado no 
                # cliente Oracle, arquivo TNSNAMES.ORA

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(uid+"/"+pwd+"@"+db) #cria a conexão
cursor = connection.cursor() # cria um cursor

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TAB") # consulta sql
result = cursor.fetchone() # busca o resultado da consulta
if result == None:
    print ("Nenhum Resultado")
    exit
else:
    while result:
        print (result[0])
        result = cursor.fetchone()

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Esse é o código que eu estou tentando executar.
O meu cx_Oracle é a versão 7.0 e já tenho a variável de ambiente configurada.

Comment: E está executando a versão correta do Python? Como está executando o script e como instalou o módulo? É bastante comum as pessoas instalarem com `pip install X`, porém a versão padrão é diferente da utilizada quando executado o script.

Comment: Então, eu usei o codígo pip install cx_Oracle, e eu to executando pela minha IDLE.
Como assim versão correta? Essa biblioteca não funciona no Python 3.6?

Comment: Qual o resultado de `pip show cx_Oracle`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Name: cx_Oracle Version: 7.0.0 summary: python interface to oracle home-page: https//oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle author: Anthony tuininga author email: anthony.tuininga@gmail.com license: bsd license location: c:\python27\lib\site-packages Requires: required-by:

Comment: E o resto? Aparece mais informações do que isso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu estava editando pq n entrou tudo

Comment: Viu? O local de instalação é `c:\python27` indicando que você instalou a biblioteca no python 2.7, mas está rodando a 3.6, que não possui a biblioteca.

Comment: Use `python3 -m pip install` para instalar todas as suas bibliotecas, pois assim saberá exatamente em qual versão estará.

Comment: Tentei rodar agora isso e deu esse resultado: python3 não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
Porém eu tenho a variável de ambiente como 3.7

Comment: Então acho que você já consegue partir daí sozinho

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o comando era com o python3 ou python? e mesmo depois de estar na pasta de python37 não consigo rodar o código sem que o erro continue

Comment: Você não está executando em uma virtualenv diferente?
Abra o console da sua IDE e instale novamente o cx_oracle